# OpenWebbeans CDI Decorator throws InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, decorator, cdi

I have a CDI decorator which calls the delegate and the delegate throws a self defined exception. Now the problem is, that it is declared in the throws clause, but is wrapped within an InvocationTargetException and the caller of the method will never know what the real exception was. What is the problem about that?

Answer (score 1):

Several bugs like this have been shaken out, but I would not be surprised if there are lingering cases like this where exceptions are not properly unwrapped.   I'd suggest opening a bug report.

Comment: Agree, this was fixed a long time ago. I consider this solved.